# jQuery to change background on table row based on values of two cells within that row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tampermonkey, userscripts

I have a tampermonkey script that highlights table rows when specific columns contain specific text.

For example the code below successfully highlights rows were column 1 contains 'M' and rows where column 3 contains 'P'.

```
$("td:nth-of-type(1):contains('M')").parent().css("background-color","#ccccff");
$("td:nth-of-type(3):contains('P')").parent().css("background-color","#ccccff");
```

How can I use an AND operator or an IF statement to highlight a row only if column 1 contains 'P' AND column 3 contains 'M'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab all the `<tr>` elements and filter that down to the ones with the `<td>` elements matching your requirements.

Once you have that filtered collection, set the background colour.

```js
const MATCH = [{
  col: 0,
  chr: "M"
}, {
  col: 2,
  chr: "P"
}]

$("tr").filter((_, tr) => {
  // get the <td> children
  const cells = $(tr).children("td")
  // Ensure each MATCH appears in each cell respectively
  return MATCH.every(({ col, chr }) => cells.eq(col).text().includes(chr))  
}).css("background-color", "#ccf")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>No capital "m" here</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>No capital "p" here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mo Money</td>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>Mo Problems</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pass the</td>
    <td>baz</td>
    <td>Mayo please</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got this is working, now I'm just trying to adapt to check column 1 for a value and column 3 for a value.

Comment: @mshiers I've updated my answer. You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71403079/edit) though so it makes sense

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is working great.  I can follow what it's doing but I never would have got that from scratch!  Lots of learning to do.  I've updated my question.